# Magento Connect Errors - Udates from 1.9.1.0 to 1.9.1.1

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.9.1

I am trying to upgrade a number of extensions from 1.9.1.0 to 1.9.1.1 in the Magento Connect Manager, however these persistently fail. The main extension I want to upgrade is Mage_Core_Modules, but despite showing the upgrade as being available, I get the following error:

**Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.1.0 (stable) 1.9.1.1 (1.9.1.0)**

CONNECT ERROR: Package community/Mage_Core_Modules failed: No releases for 'Mage_Core_Modules', skipping

And for other modules the same or a conflict error with Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.1.0:

- Interface_Adminhtml_Default 1.9.1.0 (stable) 1.9.1.1 (1.9.1.0)

  CONNECT ERROR: Package community/Interface_Adminhtml_Default failed: No releases for 'Interface_Adminhtml_Default', skipping
- Interface_Frontend_Default 1.9.1.0 (stable) 1.9.1.1 (1.9.1.0)

  CONNECT ERROR: Package community/Interface_Frontend_Default failed: No releases for 'Interface_Frontend_Default', skipping
- Lib_Mage 1.9.1.0 (stable) 1.9.1.1 (1.9.1.0)

  CONNECT ERROR: Package community/Lib_Mage 1.9.1.1 conflicts with: community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.1.0
- Mage_Compiler 1.9.1.0 (stable) 1.9.1.1 (1.9.1.0)

  CONNECT ERROR: Package community/Lib_Mage 1.9.1.1 conflicts with: community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.1.0
- Mage_Core_Adminhtml 1.9.1.0 (stable) 1.9.1.1 (1.9.1.0)

  CONNECT ERROR: Package community/Mage_Core_Adminhtml failed: No releases for 'Mage_Core_Adminhtml', skipping
- Mage_Downloader 1.9.1.0 (stable) 1.9.1.1 (1.9.1.0)

  CONNECT ERROR: Package community/Mage_Downloader failed: No releases for 'Mage_Downloader', skipping
- Magento_Mobile 1.9.1.0 (stable) 1.9.1.1 (1.9.1.0)

  CONNECT ERROR: Package community/Magento_Mobile failed: No releases for 'Magento_Mobile', skipping

I have cleared caches, switched https on/off in the config, logged in/out, turned maintenance on/off etc.. but no simple tries have worked - all suggestions very welcome. I am wary of updating via ftp but if there is no other option, maybe this is possible.

Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. I have partially solved this problem by running a reinstall of all 1.9.1.1 components that installed successfully and setting the components you listed above to upgrade at the same time. This finally upgraded the components together. However, Magento_Mobile 1.9.1.0 package is still getting this error regardless if I try to set the previous components to reinstall.

Comment: Yes I have since managed to get all installed although there is no obvious explanation as to why. Upgrading together didn't work for me. And yes Magento_Mobile package not found - same issue.

Answer (score 1):

So my solution, was up download the Magento 1.9.1.1 from Magento, https://www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/magento/

Once you have it local, upload it to your server.  Now be aware, that it assumes that you install is in a root/Magento folder if your Magneto is in a different folder, it's not a problem just un-zip locally and re-zip the files within the Magento fold the un-zip file creates.  The upload the new zip to your server where you have Magento installed.  Un-zip on the server and set it to over-write the files.  This will over-write the old out of date files and install the new files.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks - I did try this after backing up but the site crashed - "too many redirects" error - in general although ths may work - it's not an ideal solution as it does not get to the root of the problem - I don't think I have touched any of the core files so it's not clear to me what went wrong

Answer (score 1):

You can download the file from here: http://safktna.com/downloader/.cache/community/
Then upload it to your server, unpack it, rename package.xml to Magento_Mobile-1.9.1.1.xml and move it to var/package.

EDIT:
At the complete bottom of the magento download page (https://www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/magento/), there is a download called XMLConnect Module. This is the newest version

Comment: Thank you for link. Seeing as how this has had time to be written up here it amazes me I still see:
"CONNECT ERROR: Package community/Magento_Mobile failed: Package release 'Magento_Mobile' not found on server"
So what's your excuse ebay/pp?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this trick: for "Magento_Mobile"**
THEN GO FOR MAGENTO_CORE and OTHER modules

1. Go to magento connect manager and reinstall your current "Magento_Mobile".
2. This will reinstall your current/1.7 "Magento_Mobile" and also create one .tgz file here: "YOUR_MAGENTO_INSTATION_DIR/downloader/.cache/community/*"
3. Copy the name of this file; in my case this is "Magento_Mobile-1.7.0.1.22.1.tgz"
4. Now, download latest "Magento_Mobile-1.9.1.1.tgz" from here: http://safktna.com/downloader/.cache/community/
5. paste this under YOUR_MAGENTO_INSTATION_DIR/downloader/.cache/community/*
6. Delete OLD "Magento_Mobile-1.7.0.1.22.1.tgz"
7. rename new "Magento_Mobile-1.9.1.1.tgz" to "Magento_Mobile-1.7.0.1.22.1.tgz"
8. Go to magento connect manager and again reinstall "Magento_Mobile"
   THIS WILL INSTALL YOUR LATEST VERSION
   Now, to confim; click on "Check for upgrades" button this will shows as latest version installed for "Magento_Mobile"

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This could be useful for restore missing packages and force the update (be careful using --force) use this under your own risk!:

```
chmod +x mage 
./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Mage_All_Latest --force
chmod +x mage 
./mage upgrade-all --force
```

Answer (score 0):

Some modules are having version conflicts with other modules in version 1.9.1.0. You need to update the modules in the right order or just try to update all packages multiple times until the conflicts are solved by self. This works for me.

Comment: Yes - except magento_mobile.